# PHP Styling Not Appearing On Other Pages

Tags: php, css, styling

I'm new here and kind of newbie in terms of PHP so please don't be mean. Anyway, I started with a simple website and added my stylesheet to the index page as usually as I did in HTML coding. It looks like this:

```
<?php echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='design.css' />";?>
```

So the styling appears nicely on the first page, but as soon as I go to the other pages, the styling is not there. Does it mean I have to include the same code in every other page as well or is there easier way to do it? Right now I have added the same code to every other page.

I tried to search everywhere and couldn't find answer. You guys are my last hope!
Thanks in advance,
raq

Comment: Is there any code to show us..?

Comment: In fairness he did include his code - it just didn't display because he forgot to use `the correct markup`.

Comment: I did post the code, but I see it was edited by Mr. Alien. Sorry guys. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the same line into all the files you want styled. PHP is not "magic".

Depending on the case, it might be wise to create a header file you just [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in all your other pages to make changes to the header easier:

```
include 'myHeader.php';
```

This way, if you want to change something in the header, you have to do it only once, in only one file. Remember, maintainability is of key importance.

Comment: So if I create a header. php and put my styling and navigation there and include header.php in all my other sub pages then I would not have to include design and navigation separately on all the pages? Cheers

Comment: And thanks man! I can finally go on with the site! Cheers

Comment: @user2861881 yes, but keep in mind what is written in the answer **lharby** posted: if content is in different folder on server, the paths must be correct. Use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/path/myheaderfile.php` to take care of that

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, you have two options:

1. Include the CSS style in every file you have. As simple and as dumb as it may sound.
2. Start writing code using some concepts, like CMS (Content Management System). For example, if you want three pages: `home.php`, `aboutme.php`, `contact.php`, you might want to include another file, possibly called `head.php`, which will do some initialization for your code and also print the first parts of your HTML code, like `<html>`, `<head>` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

Well based on what you have posted all other files that you want to use the same css, have to reside in the same folder as the design.css file.

You might want something like:

```
 href="../css/design.css"
```

It depends on the relation between the files.

And the code will need to be served in every file that requires the css (usually a header)